# How to get started with Jekyll on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: jekyll

I followed the [official documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/):

[image]

It results in the following error:

```
orschiro@x230:~/Desktop$ sudo gem install jekyll bundler
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160906-27296-8m6gyz.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some searching around (in particular [this](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/755)), I ended up installing several packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc ruby ruby-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlibc zlib1g-dev
```

Disclaimer: Not sure all of those are needed but once I had those, it seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks! `ruby-dev` was the only one I needed, after that jekyll installed fine.